# What is Unit testing in Android , iPhone , Symbian and windows phone?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, symbian

what is unit testing in this framework Android ,iPhone, Symbian, WP7?
Can you please just give some path to get solution, to implement the unit testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is unit testing? see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 7 there is [nunit-silverlight](http://code.google.com/p/nunit-silverlight/wiki/NunitTestsWp7), which is an unofficial port of NUnit for Silverlight and includes support for WP7. There is also an [NUnit test runner](http://nunitwindowsphone7.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex, and Jeff Wilcox's [Silverlight Unit Test Runner](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/).

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with the other platforms to be able to comment, though I'm sure you'll have plenty to choose from.

Comment: I think he also wants an explanation of <i>what</i> it actually is and <i>why</i> it is useful/why to use it. I have never done it myself, so I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about unit testing iOS apps from [iOS development guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW3).